# a function definition 1 error, i tried autoformatting and pressing ctrl+t in my arduino ide and the problem still presist

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

i keep getting these Buzzer-CLiCK:33:19: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
void circling() {
^
Buzzer-CLiCK:40:17: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
void stopc () {
^
exit status 1
a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

below is my code

```
const int BUTTON_PIN = 0; // Arduino pin connected to button's pin
const int BUZZER_PIN = 12; // Arduino pin connected to Buzzer's pin
const int LED_1 = 13;
int point;
int pin[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int i = 0 ; i <= 7; i++) { // initialize serial
    pinMode(pin[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); // set arduino pin to input pull-up mode
    pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT);       // set arduino pin to output mode

  }
}

void loop() {
  int buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN); // read new state

  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("The button is being pressed");
    digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, HIGH); // turn on
    digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
circling();


  }
  else if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("The button is unpressed");
    digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, LOW);  // turn off
    digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
stopc();
  }

  void circling() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7 ; i++) {
      digitalWrite(pin[i], HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pin[i], LOW);
    }
  }

  void stopc () {
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 7; i++) {
      digitalWrite(pin[i], LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about Arduino, but I am almost 100% sure it does not support nested functions.

Comment: i try to call my subroutines as you can see above, but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: As I wrote above, I know absolutely nothing about Arduino, I have never seen any Arduino code in my life, but the *one thing* that *immediately* jumps out when you look at your code, is the nested functions. I have no idea whether Arduino supports nested functions or not, since I have never used it. However, that would be the very first thing I would check, if I were presented with a problem like this.